# Dynamically assign id to div and use that to call jquery slide effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am reading contents from JSON file and adding to div with unique IDs. I need to call jquery slide down effects to each div. Lets us consider the case, on clicking (div id=A1) it should slide down and show (div id=B1), in that way I have div with IDs A(1..N) and B(1..N).

```
var i=1;
$.each(items, function (index, item) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#A"+i).click(function(){
        $("#B"+i).slideToggle();
        });
    });

    $("#allContents").append('<div id="A'+i+'">' + item.Name + '</div>');
    $("#allContents").append('<div id="B'+i+'">' + item.Details + '</div>');
    i++;
});
```

This is the closest code I could derive to, but it is not working. If anyone could help me fix or suggest a better way to get this thing working it would be great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#allContents').on('click', 'div[id^=A]', function() {
    $('div#B' + this.id.replace('A','')).slideToggle();
});
```

#### A little explain

- `div[id^=A]` point out those `div` whose `id` start with `A`.
- `this.id` retrieve the `id` of clicked element.
- `this.id.replace('A','')` replace `A` form the `id` and get the numeric index which equal to index of `B`.
- `$('div#B' + this.id.replace('A',''))` point to element `id=B1`, `id=B2` and so on.

**Full code**

```
// you can bind event handler outside ot loop
$('#allContents').on('click', 'div[id^=A]', function() {
    $('div#B' + this.id.replace('A','')).slideToggle();
});

$.each(items, function(index, item) {
    $("#allContents").append('<div id="A' + i + '">' + item.name + '</div>');
    $("#allContents").append('<div id="B' + i + '">' + item.Details + '</div>');
    i++;
});
```

**[Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/vQzSv/9/)**

---

#### Note

As you're creating `div` from `A(1..N)` and `B(1..N)` dynamically so you need delegate event handler (aka live event).

Syntax of jQuery **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)** for delegate event is like following:

```
$(container).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction)
```